# Callback function not automatically re-rendering the react component page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
handleAddItem(s) {
this.state.items[s.listName].push({name: s.newItem});
this.render();
}



 render() {
    console.log("re-rendering");
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} />
        <div id="listsDiv" className="List">
          <Lists lists={this.state.lists} items={this.state.items} addItem={this.handleAddItem.bind(this)} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I have a callback function called handleAddItem() and for some reason, it is not automatically calling the render function when the handleAddItem() function is called in the this react component. I am having to manually call the render function and even then, it is not doing anything. Can anybody help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: In react class components you do not directly mutate state. You call `setState`: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify the state data directly, but you **cant**.

You have to call the function setState to mutate (change) the state of any data of it.

How?

```
this.setState({theData: newState})
```

Trying to modify it directly will have the behavior you are currently experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly mutate state. You should call `setState`:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

```
handleAddItem(s) {
  this.setState(({ items }) => {
    const updatedItems = {...items};
    updatedItems[s.listName] = [...updatedItems[s.listName], { name: s.newItem }];
    return {
      items: updatedItems
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In react you cannot directly edit your state variables.
You'll have to create a new temporary variable, edit that and then call `setState()` in order to achieve what you want and to trigger a re-render.

So your `handleAddItem` becomes:

```js
handleAddItem(s) {
  // Create a copy of items
  const newItems = { ...this.state.items }; // Assuming that items is an object
  // Edit the copy
  newItems[s.listName].push({ name: s.newItem });
  // Call setState
  this.setState({ items: newItems });
}
```

Comment: There are 2 errors in the code provided. `setState` is asynchronous, so you should not be using `state` before calling it. You should use a function with the current `state`. Also you are not destructuring the object that is being updated, so react will not know to update that item.